# How do I fit a complex melody in a measure?

Tags: piano, composition

I’m a classical pianist who plays/listen to mostly romantic music. And I’ve developed some complex melodies in my head that I would like to write down. Problem is I can never get everything to fit nicely in one measure, I’m terrible at counting rests and tuplets etc. I’m a completely beginner with no MT knowledge and I’m using musescore, maybe I should start of simple?

Comment: Forgive the simple question, but: is it possible your melodies are longer than a single measure, and that's why they can't quite fit?

Comment: What do you mean by "fit nicely in one measure"?

Comment: This sounds less like a music theory issue and more like an ear training issue. You might try searching the [tag:ear-training] tag to see if one or more posts is helpful to you.

Comment: Could you link to a recording of you playing the melody on piano? I think we could provide a better answer with more context.

Comment: @Richard: I’m sure that could be the case in some scenario. But then the problem becomes how do I end a motif and start another one while clearly fitting them into measures.

Comment: @musicamante: At times it’s hard for me to know where to put a eighth test or sixteenth rest between the notes.

Comment: @Aaron I think that might be it! I’ve been playing mostly in rubato so rhythm is really tough for me to master. I have trouble transcribing songs too. Will definitely check it out.

Comment: @Giovanni Sorry, I don’t have one on top of my head, but I’ll try to write when and post it sometimes. I actually have trouble replicating some of my ideas on the keyboard because the melody in my head is off pitch and I have to adjust it when I play. I’m not very good at improvising either.

Comment: Playing rubato, you'll never be able to write stuff out 'properly' using standard dots. Unless there are fermata all over the place.